# Is it possible to retrieve the iOS Photo app face match groups to use in your own app?

Tags: ios, photos

I know I can use Core image to do facial recognition, but I'm wondering if I can avoid some heavy lifting on my side for this scenario...

I'd like to build an app that can be given access to the Photos app and return only the images with 2 *specific* people occurring in the same photos. For example, "give me photos that only have these two specific people in the same photo." Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple exposes **any** API to recognize specific faces. Core Image can find faces in images, but it doesn't identify unique faces.

I'm therefore pretty sure the answer is no.